# Proving that every non constant linear function has a zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have worked up a proof and I'm not so sure if it's right, it is however for  like non math majors so it might not be that much rigorous.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Assume that there does not exist an $x$ such that:
$$f(x) = 0$$
Hence we can say that:
$$y \neq 0$$
and the above should hold for any values of x.
Now consider a linear function given by:

$$y= mx + c$$

$x$ here is given by $-\frac{c}{m}.$
Now choosing the y intercept to be $0$, we will also have $x$ = $0$.

Putting these values in the equation for a linear function we have:
$$y = m.0\ + 0$$

$$y = 0$$

But we assumed $y$ to not be equal to $0$. Hence our assumption was wrong and there does exist an $x$ such that:
$$f(x) = 0$$

Comment: Shouldn't the initial assumption be *Assume that there does $\color{red}{not}$ exist an $x$ such that...* ?

Comment: My bad I typed it wrong, I'll correct it

Comment: What is the point to make the proof indirect ? If you have found a root, you have shown that a root exists. You could also use the intermediate value theorem, but for a linear function this would be an overkill.

Comment: Also , we do not have $$y=m\cdot 0+0$$ but $$y=-\frac{c}{m}\cdot m+c=-c+c=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a non constant linear function. Write $f(x)=ax+b$, for some real number $a$ and $b$ with $a \neq 0$.

The function $f$ has a zero, since $f(x)=ax+b=0$ implies $x=-\frac{b}{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much simpler and straightforward as follows: let $\;y=f(x)=mx+c\;$ be a non-constant linear funcion. Then $\;m\neq0\;$ (otherwise the funcion's constant), and then

$$y=0\iff mx+c=0\iff mx=-c\iff x=-\frac cm$$

when we could carry on the last step since we know $\;m\neq0\;$ . Thus,

$$f\left(-\frac cm\right)=m\left(-\frac cm\right)+c=-c+c=0\implies f\;\text{ has a zero, and it is}\;\;-\frac cm$$